# c++ append a struct into a binary file

Tags: c++, file, struct, append

I have my struct:

```
struct a
{
  int    x;
  float  f;
  double d;
  char   c;
  char   s[50];
};
```

and I wish append each time into my timer schedule into a binary file.

```
// declaration
std::ofstream outFile;

// constructor:
outFile.open( "save.dat", ios::app );

// tick:
outFile << a << endl;
```

but inside the save.dat appears only this:

```
0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..0C3A0000..
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you giving us the whole code? You're probably just printing the pointer value. You have to overload the `<<` operator, or otherwise write some serialization code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're currently doing is writing the address of the struct definition.
What you want to do is use [ostream::write](http://ostream%3a%3awrite)

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myStruct), sizeof(a));
```

This will work as long as your struct is a POD (Plain Old Data) type (which your example is). POD type means that all members are of fixed size.

If you on the other hand have variable sized members then you would need to write out each member one by one.

Comment: That's probably still not a great idea, because the struct will have platform-dependent padding...

Comment: @ghiboz: why do you think you're overwriting it when you use ios:app?

Answer (score 2):

A sensible way to serialize custom objects is to overload your own output stream operator:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const a & x)
{
  o.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.x), sizeof(int));
  o.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x.f), sizeof(float));
  /* ... */
  return o;
}

a x;
std::ofstream ofile("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
ofile << a;
```

This is still platform-dependent, so to be a bit safer, you should probably use fixed-width data types like `int32_t` etc.

It might also not be the best idea semantically to use `<<` for binary output, since it's often used for *formatted* output. Perhaps a slightly safer method would be to write a function `void serialize(const a &, std::ostream &);`

Comment: And probably still not a great idea, because you have little/big endian systems...

Comment: Sure, you have to design that for your needs... it all depends. If you're in a x86/x64 server farm (like Facebook) and you need high throughput, you might consider this as an efficient though limited-scope solution; if you want to be super platform-independent, you'd have to document the binary format precisely. It all depends on your needs! (You could also belabour the topic of float serialization if you like... it really just depends.)